# Is it possible to use code from a flutter package and modify it?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

There is this package contacts_service in flutter and I want to use its methods but I want to customize the Contact's Model. So I thought I could just copy the file's code and modify it in my own project. But the problem is that it says:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method addContact on channel 
github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_contacts)
```

And I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: OOP principles. Subclass it and override the methods you want to add more functions. Or use an adapter class to modify a methods behaviour.

Comment: What he says. Or you can open the package folder in explorer. Then copy the whole folder inside your lib folder. In pubspec.yaml change the package dependency to the package u saved in lib.

Comment: there are too many possibility about Unhandled Exception: 
MissingPluginException. Could you share your code to github so we can help.

Comment: @FadhliS I did copy the code that way but I didn't know if it's a good way to do it. Now it works, i just had to copy the code the way it was without modificating the fields, I only could add extra fields. I think because of the method's implementation.

Comment: @inoi This might be abit advance for you but the method or variable u wanna change might be used by different dependencies in the package. Read the code and if you are using intelliJ, you can hold ctrl on your keyboard and click on the variables/methods to see its usages. There might be instances where the developer implements native code and call it using channels.